# After blocking someone, how do I keep someone from chatting?

Tags: draw-something

I blocked someone who was asking for personal information. He/She became rude in his/her drawings and chat. I blocked this person but they are still sending chat messages. How can I delete/block chats from this person?

Comment: report him that way he'll get banned...

Answer (score 1):

I personally think the best way to stop the rude drawings/messages is to stop drawing with them. You can delete a person by swiping their name and pressing delete.

Comment: did this help at all?